# How to read attributes of a python object with __slots__ in gdb

Tags: python, gdb

I have a core dump of a Python process which I'm trying to inspect. In particular, I'm interested in the value of a particular `Decimal` instance.

I've loaded the Python extensions to gdb, specifically I'm using the [libpython.py distributed with Python 2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Tools/gdb/libpython.py). And this provides some degree of inspection into the Python language state from within gdb. Notably, the inspection is based on recreating a "proxy object" for objects from the inferior process, and those proxy objects are created by copying the `__dict__` of the object being inspected.

Unfortunately, instances of a class with `__slots__` have no `__dict__`, and so [`.get_attr_dict()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/103b8d9f9179089019ddb363ec0098b63816001b/Tools/gdb/libpython.py#L462) returns None, and thus the attributes of the `Decimal` instance don't seem to be inspectable without some effort.

Furthermore, since this is a core dump and not a live process, I can't simply call [`PyObject_GenericGetAttr`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GenericGetAttr). It seems my only option is to traverse the structures manually within gdb until I get at the value.

How might such a manual inspection be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Begin with some value to inspect. For this example, we'll look at `self._int`. Begin by getting the address of `self`, and saving it to a convenience variable:

```
(gdb) py-locals
self = <Decimal at remote 0x7f2d6cbc0280>
[...]
(gdb) set $self = (PyObject*)0x7f2d6cbc0280
```

Slotted attributes are implemented as [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors), and the descriptor for the `_int` attribute is stored in the type's (in this case, `Decimal`) dictionary. Fortunately libpython already prints python dicts, so we don't need to manually interpret the dictionary structure but can just read the address of the descriptor from the output and save it to another convenience variable:

```
(gdb) p $self->ob_type->tp_dict
$5 = {[...] '_int': <member_descriptor at remote 0x7f2d8e527320>, [...]}
(gdb) set $int = (PyMemberDescrObject *)0x7f2d8e527320
```

Slotted attributes are stored at some offset from the object pointer (`$self`), and we can get that offset like this:

```
(gdb) p *$int->d_member
$9 = {name = 0x7f2d931d3774 "_int", type = 16, offset = 24, flags = 0, doc = 0x0}
```

To interpret the value we must also take note of the type. The implementation of [`PyMember_GetOne`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/74bede0d503d0508e9590f4ad65ee48b0ab93db6/Python/structmember.c#L64-L132) shows how the value should be cast according to the type, and we can see in [structmember.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/74bede0d503d0508e9590f4ad65ee48b0ab93db6/Include/structmember.h#L45-L76) that type 16 from above corresponds to `T_OBJECT_EX`. Now we add the `offset` from the descriptor to `$self`, cast it appropriately, and print the result:

```
(gdb) p *(PyObject**)((char *)$self+24)
$14 = '600'
```

And there you have it: `self._int` is `'600'`.